# Capacitance/length limitations when daisy-chaining microcontrollers

Tags: circuit-design, serial, pullup, push-pull, tri-state

I'm doing a daisy-chain of microcontrollers, with a half-duplex bidirectional line going from DOUT/DIN ports.

I was thinking of doing tristate for the ports, and have a pull-up resistor connected to the supply rail, like how I2C is designed to allow multimaster bus control. I know I2C has a capacitance limit of ~400 pF, limiting length of master-slave connections.

I'm wondering whether the following rough schematic would have any similar implications I'm not aware of.

It seems to me since each U1-U2 connection is isolated from the rest, capacitance will not build up across the whole network, but perhaps there are other costs, e.g. internal to the microcontrollers which impose length limitations.

[image: schematic]

**Additional details:**

- The microcontroller is probably going to be the Attiny414 or similar model. That's +/-40 mA pin sink/source current
- Likely will use bit-banging instead of a standard protocol. I think I2C is the most similar to what I'm planning, but foregoing the clock synchronization line.
- Minimum speed 6.5 kbps. Likely anything more than 150 kbps is overkill.
- Maximum 90 mm bus between microcontrollers
- Bus is PCB trace, with PCB-to-PCB connections in between. The capacitance will probably around 0.7 pF/cm. Pin capacitance maximum 10 pF, so perhaps ~27 pF overall.
- Logic levels .3*VCC (1.5V) and .7*VCC (3.5V)
- Fall time is 1.3 ns, that's from the mocrocontroller's datasheet. For rise time, I suppose taking inspiration from I2C protocol and having it be ~12% of bitrate (150 kbps), that'd be 800 ns.
- Maximum pull-up resistor: 800 ns/(0.8473*27 pF) = 35k
- Was thinking the microcontrollers may be connected to others in standby/power down mode, but would have a wakeup interrupt on DIN/DOUT.
- Would like to be able to do a daisy-chain of up to 1k of these at most (practical maximum probably more like 250.)

Comment: The answer depends on what cable you will use and how. What protocol you intend to use? At what speed? What rise/fall times are required? How much capacitace you tolerate? How long is the bus between MCUs? What cable you will use and how much it has capacitance? What logic levels you intend to use? How much current the MCU can sink? Will any powered MCU or pulled up bus be connected to an unpowered MCU?

Comment: Okay thanks, I realize now the question was too general. I've added some additional details, and calculated some of the numbers you mentioned. Do you have any advice for my specific case?

Comment: EE top tip: f = femto. F = farad.

Comment: Will these be on a PCB with ground plane, or connected by cabling?

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve with this, but this is practically falling to your knees and begging the Gods of Electronics to smite you with single-point failures.  If any one processor fails to operate correctly, all of the processors after it will never get a message.  If you use a protocol that calls for looping things around, that single-point failure will mean that _nothing_ gets around the loop.  Why not CAN, or RS-485, or some other established multi-drop protocol?

Comment: So just PCB + ground (was thinking ground traces, but haven't got that far in the design really). The idea is to have many devices which can plug into eachother in a rearrangeable way. Network topology would be a binary tree. Originally I was going to do I2C, but I later estimated it would only be able to hit ~40 devices before reaching capacitance limits. The daisy-chain idea (with 2x DOUT however for binary tree topology, not pictured in schematic) was to get past the I2C device limitation.

Comment: Not ideal of course with single-point failures as mentioned, but the application is non-critical and I think having the devices be as cheap as possible outweighs the need to gracefully handle device failures. I've heard mention of CAN/RS-485, but haven't looked into them at all, so I will look into those more deeply. Thanks for the suggestion